# Calculating area of residential area wihin multiple ring buffer in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, buffer, area, overlay

I need to calculate the size of residential area within 0-250m, 250-500m and 500-750m of a bus stop.

I have made a multiple ring buffer around the bus stops. And I have a shapefile of the residential area.

But I can't work out how you can combine the shapefile of residential area with the multiple ring buffer and then calculate the size of residential area of each buffer ring.

Does someone know how to do this?

Comment: Be aware that multiple ring buffers can be generated in two different ways depending on the Dissolve option parameter. If you set it to All, you actually get rings. If you set it to None, you get overlapping circles (each buffer also contains the area of any smaller buffers within it). Be sure to use the correct method/figures depending on whether you want the *total* area within 500m or just the area *between* 250 and 500m (which you could then add to the area within 250m to *get* the total).

Answer (score 3):

To do this I would use two tools:

1. [Intersect (Analysis)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000000p000000):

> Computes a geometric intersection of the input features. Features or
>   portions of features which overlap in all layers and/or feature
>   classes will be written to the output feature class.

then

2. [Summary Statistics (Analysis)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000001z000000)

> Calculates summary statistics for field(s) in a table.